# Java: substring.matches numbers

Tags: java, string, methods, numbers, substring

I'm trying to check if a my substring within my teleInput string contain numbers but I can't seem to get it return true. The results always ends up as false, what am I doing wrong.

```
String teleInput = "(555)555-5555";
boolean returntT = teleInput.substring(1,3).matches(".*[0-9].*");
```

I'm an extreme beginner so I don't know if I'm missing something obvious, like mixing methods or maybe something is wrong with the rest of my code, either way, I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: This could be interesting for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507162/most-elegant-isnumeric-solution-for-java

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your substring - you are only returning **two** characters: the second parameter is the index up to, but not including, the last character. To get 3 characters, you need:

```
teleInput.substring(1,4)
```

So try this (notice that matches only needs to check that it's "all digits", because the length is already know to be 3):

```
teleInput.substring(1,4).matches("\\d*");
```

Or just forget substring and use matches alone:

```
teleInput.matches(".\\d{3}.*");
```

Which is the regex for "any character then 3 digits then anything".

But you can validate the entire input in one line:

```
teleInput.matches("(.\\d{3}){3}\\d");
```

You might have to read up on regex to understand this pattern, but it works!

---

Note: matches() must match the *entire* string to be true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the 2nd character in your string is number, you can do it like this:

```
String teleInput = "(555)555-5555";

boolean returntT = teleInput.substring(1,2).matches("[0-9]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line:

```
boolean returntT = teleInput.substring(1,3).matches(".*[0-9].*");
```

You should be doing:

```
boolean returntT = teleInput.substring(1,3).matches("[0-9]+");
```

OR this:

```
boolean returntT = teleInput.substring(1,3).matches("\\d{2}");
```

Regex `[0-9]+` will make sure that the given input has only 1 or more digits in it. For good tutorial on regex read: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: You never need ^ or $ in matches()

Comment: Actually, it's really important to remember that matches must match the whole string - all other languages I can think of only need to match *part* of the string for their equivalent method - java is unusual in this respect so it's easy to forget